# Tools to Monitor particular application data consumption for a period of time

Tags: networking, software-installation, network-manager, internet, network-monitoring

I am looking for a package to monitor bandwidth consumed by one particular app, e.g., the data of a Zoom meeting. i need to track that consumption.
Can someone suggest any software that you know.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I will only mention one of such tools here. You'll notice that you can see the bandwith consumption per application in the image bellow. This is just one of the tools (And it's closed source but has a free trial period).

However, there are numerous tools with which you can achieve what you need. You can have a complete detailed solution [here](https://www.dnsstuff.com/linux-network-monitoring-tools) (In as much as the link is not broken...). I will nevertheless list some of the tools at the bottom.

---

**SolarWinds NetFlow Traffic Analyzer**

Of the closed-source products on this list, NetFlow Traffic Analyzer (NTA) provides a particularly broad range of monitoring functions for a scalable number of nodes in your network. It is notable among closed-source IT setups for being fully functional during its 30-day free trial period, so if your company is unsure if it’s worth the investment, SolarWinds lets you see for yourself at no cost.

[image]

Once you’ve gained a basic understanding of how SolarWinds NTA works through the free trial, you’ll be able to easily operate the tool due to its interactive, visualized data displays. One of the most useful features of NTA is its ease of use for non-experts—if you’ve got a basic idea of how Linux network monitoring works, this intuitive, interactive program will enable you to monitor and analyze network traffic without a great degree of technical expertise.

NTA also provides visualized bandwidth monitoring for users to observe the capacity of the network units, and to see if any IT issues are pending. Moreover, the tool’s scalability helps ensure you can adjust your network units to the capacity that seems fit.

NTA is easy to use because of its Performance Analysis Dashboard. SolarWinds software is well known for providing a high degree of color-coded and searchable visual data. The Performance Analysis Dashboard helps you analyze your NetFlow with a great deal of precision, while operating in a streamlined visual display.

Another noteworthy aspect of NTA is its Class-Based Quality of Service (CBQoS) policy. Twenty-first century networks often operate using cloud-based applications, and SolarWinds recognizes some of these take higher priority in using network bandwidth. CBQoS helps you prioritize which applications should take up bandwidth, so these apps travel more quickly in your network.

This Linux network monitoring software isn’t just a tool for measuring bandwidth and capacity—it also alerts you when something’s wrong. NTA offers traffic-based alerts when it suspects a device is malfunctioning, and it can be a crucial tool for detecting threats in your network. In addition, while other network monitoring tools allow the central controller to view any new devices accessing your system and how much traffic they’re conducting, NetFlow Traffic Analyzer takes this a step further—it provides you with alerts if unusual traffic is detected toward port 0, the neutral port attackers often use to access a system.

---

**A. Best Closed-Source Linux Network Monitoring Tools:**

> 1. SolarWinds NetFlow Traffic Analyzer
> 2. Paessler PRTG Network Monitor
> 3. Nagios Network Analyzer
> 4. Zenoss Cloud

**B. Top Open-Source Linux Network Monitoring Tools:**

> 5. Icinga 2
> 6. OpenNMS
> 7. Cacti
> 8. Zabbix
> 9. Pandora FMS
> 10. LibreNMS
> 11. Prometheus
> 12. EventSentry Light
> 13. Observium Community
> 14. Monitorix
> 15. Ganglia
> 16. Htop
> 17. BMW-NG
> 18. EtherApe
> 19. IBMonitor

---

I hope this helps you solve the issue at hand.

Comment: @DhanasekarChellamuthu You're welcome! :)